# How Magento 2 url rewrite works?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I can't understand , how url rewrite module work in magento 2 ? Can we regenerate all products & category url in magento 2 like magento 1 ? or is there any specific any other method for that.

Comment: Does [this](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite-configuration.html?Highlight=url%20rewrite) help?